# Do not rotate UIView but rotate UIImageView's inside it

Tags: ios, uiview, rotation, scroll

I know there's lots posted about it, but I can't find the best solution.

I have a "holder" view (UIView) that contains many scrollViews stretching horizontally in Landscape mode. Each scrollview contains view's containing images, that are scrolled vertically. Again, the whole thing is in Landscape.

What I want is, when I rotate to portrait mode the "holder" view containing everything stays the same, meaning is now a column, the scroll views rotate meaning scrolling is horizontal, but the content of scrollviews (views containing images) rotates.

I tried writing a UIView child class (for the "holder" view) and putting the following method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

in the same way I was hoping to deal with the sub views residing in my "holder" view, but that din't work. What could be the best way? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set that your supported orientations are the ones you want and the observe [`UIDevice`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html) orientation changes to handle manually the other orientations. Here you have an example:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

- (void)deviceDidRotate:(NSNotification *)notification;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(deviceDidRotate:)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {

    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}

#pragma mark - Private methods

- (void)deviceDidRotate:(NSNotification *)notification {

    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    /* Handle manually the rotation
       For instance, apply a transform to a UIView:
       CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians);
       self.aView.transform = transform; */
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks, the CGAffineTransform was what I was looking for. I have one more question regarding syntax. I put some objects in an array and want to rotate those objects, something like    for (loop thorugh array) { CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2.0);[[myLetterObjects objectAtIndex:i]] transform = transform;} how would the syntax work here? the dot like [myLetterObjects objectAtIndex:i].transform = transform; won't do it.

Comment: @Au Ris Inside the loop: UIView * aView = [myLetterObjects objectAtIndex:i]; [aView setTransform:transform];